# Шейдер воды перестает работать unity3d

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, шейдеры

Скачал бесплатный Asset Package с шейдером воды, разместил на сцене.

[Ссылка на асет в Asset Store](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/lowpoly-water-107563)

Все работает хорошо за исключением одного момента. При повороте камеры(когда она находится близко к земле) вода перестает нормально отрисовываться.
Вот код шейдера:

```
Shader "LowPolyWater/WaterShaded" {
Properties { 

    _BaseColor ("Base color", COLOR)  = ( .54, .95, .99, 0.5) 
    _SpecColor ("Specular Material Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1) 
    _Shininess ("Shininess", Float) = 10
    _ShoreTex ("Shore & Foam texture ", 2D) = "black" {} 
     
    _InvFadeParemeter ("Auto blend parameter (Edge, Shore, Distance scale)", Vector) = (0.2 ,0.39, 0.5, 1.0)

    _BumpTiling ("Foam Tiling", Vector) = (1.0 ,1.0, -2.0, 3.0)
    _BumpDirection ("Foam movement", Vector) = (1.0 ,1.0, -1.0, 1.0) 

    _Foam ("Foam (intensity, cutoff)", Vector) = (0.1, 0.375, 0.0, 0.0) 
    [MaterialToggle] _isInnerAlphaBlendOrColor("Fade inner to color or alpha?", Float) = 0 
}


CGINCLUDE 

    #include "UnityCG.cginc" 
    #include "UnityLightingCommon.cginc" // for _LightColor0


    sampler2D _ShoreTex;
    sampler2D_float _CameraDepthTexture;
  
    uniform float4 _BaseColor;  
    uniform float _Shininess;
     
    uniform float4 _InvFadeParemeter;
    
    uniform float4 _BumpTiling;
    uniform float4 _BumpDirection;
 
    uniform float4 _Foam; 
    float _isInnerAlphaBlendOrColor; 
    #define VERTEX_WORLD_NORMAL i.normalInterpolator.xyz 


    struct appdata
    {
        float4 vertex : POSITION;
        float3 normal : NORMAL;
    };
 
    
    struct v2f
    {
        float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
        float4 normalInterpolator : TEXCOORD0;
        float4 viewInterpolator : TEXCOORD1;
        float4 bumpCoords : TEXCOORD2;
        float4 screenPos : TEXCOORD3;
        float4 grabPassPos : TEXCOORD4; 
        half3 worldRefl : TEXCOORD6;
        float4 posWorld : TEXCOORD7;
        float3 normalDir : TEXCOORD8;

        UNITY_FOG_COORDS(5)
    }; 
 
    inline half4 Foam(sampler2D shoreTex, half4 coords) 
    {
        half4 foam = (tex2D(shoreTex, coords.xy) * tex2D(shoreTex,coords.zw)) - 0.125;
        return foam;
    }

    v2f vert(appdata_full v)
    {
        v2f o;
        UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(v2f, o);

        
        half3 worldSpaceVertex = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld,(v.vertex)).xyz;
        half3 vtxForAni = (worldSpaceVertex).xzz;
 
        half3   offsets = half3(0,0,0);
        half3   nrml = half3(0,1,0);
        
        v.vertex.xyz += offsets;
         
        half2 tileableUv = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld,(v.vertex)).xz;
        
        o.bumpCoords.xyzw = (tileableUv.xyxy + _Time.xxxx * _BumpDirection.xyzw) * _BumpTiling.xyzw;

        o.viewInterpolator.xyz = worldSpaceVertex - _WorldSpaceCameraPos;
        o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
        o.screenPos=ComputeScreenPos(o.pos); 
        o.normalInterpolator.xyz = nrml;
        o.viewInterpolator.w = saturate(offsets.y);
        o.normalInterpolator.w = 1; 
        
        UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.pos);
        half3 worldNormal = UnityObjectToWorldNormal(v.normal); 
        float4x4 modelMatrix = unity_ObjectToWorld;
        float4x4 modelMatrixInverse = unity_WorldToObject; 
        o.posWorld = mul(modelMatrix, v.vertex);
        o.normalDir = normalize( mul(float4(v.normal, 0.0), modelMatrixInverse).xyz); 

        float3 worldPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex).xyz;
        float3 worldViewDir = normalize(UnityWorldSpaceViewDir(worldPos)); 
        o.worldRefl = reflect(-worldViewDir, worldNormal);

        return o;
    }
 
     half4 calculateBaseColor(v2f input)  
         {
            float3 normalDirection = normalize(input.normalDir);
 
            float3 viewDirection = normalize(
               _WorldSpaceCameraPos - input.posWorld.xyz);
            float3 lightDirection;
            float attenuation;
 
            if (0.0 == _WorldSpaceLightPos0.w) // directional light?
            {
               attenuation = 1.0; // no attenuation
               lightDirection = normalize(_WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz);
            } 
            else // point or spot light
            {
               float3 vertexToLightSource = 
                  _WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz - input.posWorld.xyz;
               float distance = length(vertexToLightSource);
               attenuation = 1.0 / distance; // linear attenuation 
               lightDirection = normalize(vertexToLightSource);
            }
 
            float3 ambientLighting = 
               UNITY_LIGHTMODEL_AMBIENT.rgb * _BaseColor.rgb;
 
            float3 diffuseReflection = 
               attenuation * _LightColor0.rgb * _BaseColor.rgb
               * max(0.0, dot(normalDirection, lightDirection));
 
            float3 specularReflection;
            if (dot(normalDirection, lightDirection) < 0.0) 
               // light source on the wrong side?
            {
               specularReflection = float3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); 
                  // no specular reflection
            }
            else  
            {
               specularReflection = attenuation * _LightColor0.rgb  * _SpecColor.rgb * pow(max(0.0, dot(reflect(-lightDirection, normalDirection), viewDirection)), _Shininess);
            }

            return half4(ambientLighting + diffuseReflection  + specularReflection, 1.0);
         }

    half4 frag( v2f i ) : SV_Target
    { 
 
        half4 edgeBlendFactors = half4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        
        #ifdef WATER_EDGEBLEND_ON
            half depth = SAMPLE_DEPTH_TEXTURE_PROJ(_CameraDepthTexture, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(i.screenPos));
            depth = LinearEyeDepth(depth);
            edgeBlendFactors = saturate(_InvFadeParemeter * (depth-i.screenPos.w));
            edgeBlendFactors.y = 1.0-edgeBlendFactors.y;
        #endif
        
 
        half4 baseColor = calculateBaseColor(i);
       
 
        half4 foam = Foam(_ShoreTex, i.bumpCoords * 2.0);
        baseColor.rgb += foam.rgb * _Foam.x * (edgeBlendFactors.y + saturate(i.viewInterpolator.w - _Foam.y));
        if( _isInnerAlphaBlendOrColor==0)
            baseColor.rgb += 1.0-edgeBlendFactors.x;
        if(  _isInnerAlphaBlendOrColor==1.0)
            baseColor.a  =  edgeBlendFactors.x;
        UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, baseColor);
        return baseColor;
    }
    
ENDCG

Subshader
{
    Tags {"RenderType"="Transparent" "Queue"="Transparent"}
    
    Lod 500
    ColorMask RGB
    
    GrabPass { "_RefractionTex" }
    
    Pass {
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
            ZTest LEqual
            ZWrite Off
            Cull Off
        
            CGPROGRAM
        
            #pragma target 3.0
        
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma multi_compile_fog
        
            #pragma multi_compile WATER_EDGEBLEND_ON WATER_EDGEBLEND_OFF 
        
            ENDCG
    }
}


Fallback "Transparent/Diffuse"
}
```

Вот так это выглядит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот параметры камеры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С шейдерами очень мало знаком, подскажите, где может скрываться проблема, спасибо.